# How to pass a string value in sqoop free form query

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I need to import data from few different SQL servers which have same tables, table structure and even primary key value. So to uniquely identify a record, ingested from a SQLserver say "S1", i want to have a extra column - say "serverName" in my hive tables. How should i add this in my sqoop free form query.

All i want to do is pass a hardcoded value along with list of columns such that the hardcoded column value should get stored in Hive. Once done, I can take care of dynamically changing this value depending upon the server data.

```
sqoop import --connect "connDetails" --username "user"  --password "pass" --query "select col1, col2, col3, 'S1' from table where \$CONDITIONS" --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table stg.T1  --split-by col1 --as-textfile  --target-dir T1  --hive-drop-import-delims
```

**S1** being the hardcoded value here. I am thinking in SQL-way that when you pass a hardcode value, same is returned as the query result. Any pointers how to get this done?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Actually it just needed an alias for the hardcoded value. So the sqoop command executed is -

```
sqoop import --connect "connDetails" --username "user"  --password "pass" --query "select col1, col2, col3, 'S1' as serverName from table where \$CONDITIONS" --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table stg.T1  --split-by col1 --as-textfile  --target-dir T1  --hive-drop-import-delims
```